# LATEX MATH MODE ERROR misssing $..$

Tags: math-mode

[image]

HELP Its saying im missing $ .. $ but I was messing with it and putting them in but it kept on formatting super weird and the best looking one was without the math mode which I have below. I don't know what to do :(

Comment: (1) You cannot have blank lines in most math enrivonments, so remove the blank lines or comment then out with `%`, (2) You're already in a math environment, so it's an error to put `$`'s around `\Omega`, (3) you should *never* use the eqnarray environment (see [here](https://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/) — and especially if you're not going to align anything), (4) don't post screen shots of code; post code. We can't copy and paste screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Your code containts two syntax errors -- the empty lines in a display-math environment, and the use of `$` to initiate and terminate inline math mode when you're already in display math mode -- and also places the `\nonumber` directive on the wrong line. (I won't even talk about the physics error, as that is presumably not the point of your posting...)

Moreover, your code also doesn't exactly do a good job of typesetting scientific quantities and units according to established typographic standards. Please look into using the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) package and, in particular, its `\unit` and `\qty` macros for making this task easier to handle.

[image]

In the following example code block, do note the use of `\volt`, `\ohm`, and `\ampere` and the fact that the associated units are typeset as upright rather than as slanted/italic letters, along with the "thinspace" gaps inserted between quantitities and associated units. All this is expected from proper scientific typesetting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for '\qty' macro
\begin{document}
\[
I_{\mathrm{tot}}=\qty{9}{\volt} \big/ % division, not multiplication
     \qty[parse-numbers=false]{(1/10+1/10)}{\ohm} 
   = \qty{1.8}{\ampere}
\]
\end{document}
```